# Table UPDATE in SQL Server slows down an Index Seek in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, query-optimization, temp-tables, non-clustered-index

I have the following query in SQL Server Management Studio 18, let's call it Query1:

```
SELECT
    stage.IDContratto,
    SUM(stageReg.Costo) AS Costo
FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita AS stage
INNER JOIN STAGING.TabCommesse AS stageCom ON stage.CodiceContratto = stageCom.CodiceContrattoCommessa
INNER JOIN STAGING.TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse AS stageReg
    ON stageCom.CodiceCommessa = stageReg.CodiceCommessaCalcolato
    AND stageReg.DataRegistrazione BETWEEN stage.StartDate AND stage.EndDate
WHERE stageCom.SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa = 1
GROUP BY stage.IDContratto
```

TabContrattiRedditivita has 16K rows, TabCommesse has 49K rows, and TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse has 6.8 MLN rows. Query1 returns 1.200 rows. Because of the IX_CostiCommessa non-clustered index I put on TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse (details below) this query completes in about 3 min, which all in all is fine to me. You can see the actual exec plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkS9JThbY).

However I actually use Query1 inside an UPDATE of TabContrattiRedditivita, let's call it Query2:

```
UPDATE STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita
SET
    ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo,
    TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo
FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita AS stage
INNER JOIN (Query1) AS costi ON stage.IDContratto = costi.IDContratto
```

And Query 2 completes in 16 min or more, which is not fine. You can see the actual exec plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk-Jv32WF).

You might think it's a problem of writing operations, but in the following I report some strange facts that led me to think it is not.

First, Query1 returns just 1.200 rows, so the writing operations are insignificant (in my ETL I do UPDATEs 2 to 3 orders of magnitude higher without any performance problem). Second, as you can see above the actual exec plan of the subquery Query1 inside Query2 looks identical to the actual exec plan of Query1 executed alone (except for percentages, of course). Third, live statistics about Query2 seems to reveal that **the Index Seek on TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse is slowing down Query2, not the UPDATE operation**, which instead takes < 1 sec (notice the total running time was 17 min 11 sec):

[image]

[image]

This is the same Index Seek that in Query1 only took about 3 min (total running time: 3 min 10 sec):

[image]

So it seems like the mere presence of the UPDATE is causing Query1 to slow down dramatically even *before* the UPDATE is executed.

Here come the twist: if I copy my datawarehouse tables TabContrattiRedditivita, TabCommesse and TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse into temp tables #Tab1, #Tab2 and #Tab3 respectively, and then I create the same PKs and indexes on these temp tables, then all suddenly works. Query1:

```
SELECT
    stage.IDContratto,
    SUM(stageReg.Costo) AS Costo
FROM #Tab1 AS stage
INNER JOIN #Tab2 AS stageCom ON stage.CodiceContratto = stageCom.CodiceContrattoCommessa
INNER JOIN #Tab3 AS stageReg
    ON stageCom.CodiceCommessa = stageReg.CodiceCommessaCalcolato
    AND stageReg.DataRegistrazione BETWEEN stage.StartDate AND stage.EndDate
WHERE stageCom.SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa = 1
GROUP BY stage.IDContratto
```

Execution time about 3 min, just as the previous Query1; actual exec plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJArB0nWF). Query2:

```
UPDATE #Tab1
SET
    ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo,
    TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo
FROM #Tab1 AS stage
INNER JOIN (Query1) AS costi ON stage.IDContratto = costi.IDContratto
```

**Execution time about 3 min 10 sec, instead of 16 or 17 min like the previous Query2**; actual exec plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ7vLRhZK).

How can this be? Any clue about how to fix this?

---

Note: I also tried a couple of alternatives, which revealed themselves uneffective.

I tried to use a #temp table: I put Query1 `INTO #temp`, then executing Query2 this way:

```
UPDATE STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita
SET
    ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo,
    TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo
FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita AS stage
INNER JOIN #temp AS costi ON stage.IDContratto = costi.IDContratto
```

The results are the same, but this time Query1 is the slow part: Query1 runs in 16 min, with the Index Seek on Tab3 very slow, then Query2 runs in few seconds.

I also tried to use a CTE in two ways. Way number 1:

```
WITH CostoRegistrazioni AS (Query1)

UPDATE STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita
SET
    ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo,
    TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo
FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita AS stage
INNER JOIN CostoRegistrazioni AS costi ON stage.IDContratto = costi.IDContratto
```

Way number 2:

```
WITH updateStage AS (
    SELECT
        ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti,
        TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti,
        costi.Costo
    FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita AS stage
    INNER JOIN (Query1) AS costi ON stage.IDContratto = costi.IDContratto
)
UPDATE updateStage
SET
    ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += Costo,
    TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += Costo
```

In both cases same result: Query1 runs in 16 min, with the Index Seek on TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse very slow.

---

Technical details

1. Where you see Clustered Index Scans on PK_TableName in the above exec plans, PK_TableName are just the standard clustered indexes that SQL Server creates on the table's PK. IX_CostiCommessa is instead defined as follows (on Tab3 is exactly the same):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CostiCommessa]
ON [STAGING].[TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse] (
    [DataRegistrazione] ASC,
    [CodiceCommessaCalcolato] ASC
)
INCLUDE (
    [Costo],
    [SeRisorsaInterna],
    [SeRisolutivo]
)
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = ON,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON,
    FILLFACTOR = 100
)
```

2. Temp tables are defined as follows:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Tab1
FROM STAGING.TabContrattiRedditivita

SELECT *
INTO #Tab2
FROM STAGING.TabCommesse

SELECT *
INTO #Tab3
FROM STAGING.TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse
```

3. You may have noticed some missed index notifications in the actual exec plans above. I already tried to create them, the only effect was slowing down the queries (even Query1).
4. The warning you may have seen in the actual exec plan of Query2 is an ExcessiveGrant, which I'm not sure how to interpret:

[image]

Comment: How many rows are coming back from the inner query?
Also is that the actual execution plan and not estimated?

Comment: How about losing the join and using an updatable CTE?

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) then [edit] your question to give us more information. We need to see the indexes on your tables, especially the big one.

Comment: Looks to me like the common denominator in the slower queries is that you are writing data, not just reading it. What are the growth settings on your database and log files? Same question for tempdb.

Comment: Please share the actual query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, please also [edit] your question and add the index definitions.

Comment: An updatable CTE/derived table would make sense here, also the `Hash Match` and `Sort` should be gotten rid of with better indexing

Comment: @Andrew about 1.200 rows. The exec plan screenshot you see is the estimated one, but the structure of the real time exec plan is the same. I'm going to share more technical details during the day.

Comment: Ok not as many rows as i thought you would say, but as people have said its doing at least 1200 writes (which shouldn't take that long, unless it has to scan the table for each record, seeking to it is the goal), get the actual execution plan as it is so much better than the estimated, the estimated is a waste of time compared to the actual :)

Comment: I had to rewrite the question because I discovered new features. In the previous version, Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3 were temp tables in which I copied the actual datawarehouse tables and recreated the indexes there. But then I discovered that Query2 executed this way only takes 3 min. If instead I execute Query2 with the actual datawarehouse tables, it takes 16 min. I tried to clarify the whole picture in the question. _CTE solution still to be tested_.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you, I added the details

Comment: @Charlieface thank you, I added exec plans via Brentozar and index definitions

Comment: @allmhuran I don't think it's a matter of writing data, see the rewritten question to know why. Btw I don't know what do you mean by "growth settings", and what kind of log files are you interested at?

Comment: In your question, you had `query1` which executed quickly as a select, but slowly when the same query was writing data to tempdb. So my hypothesis was that tempdb might be under write pressure. This could be because it is configured to allocate space in too-small chunks (`select growth from tempdb.sys.database_files`), or possibly allocation map contention, the solution to which would be to split tempdb into more files.

Comment: @allmhuran `select growth from tempdb.sys.database_files` returns a column with 5 rows in which each entry is 0.

Comment: @Stu updatable CTE tested, nothing changed. See the updated question for details.

Comment: @Charlieface updatable CTE tested, nothing changed. See the updated question for details.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really understood what was meant by "updatable CTE" in this context. The point is that Query1 already contains a reference to `TabContrattiRedditivita` so there is no need to rejoin it. You should update Query1 directly without any other joins.

Comment: @Charlieface I think I'm forced to join `TabContrattiRedditivita` twice. In Query1 I aggregate a field of `TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse` (`Costo`) by a field of `TabContrattiRedditivita` (`IDContratto`). If I use `TabContrattiRedditivita` only once then I should write `SET ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti = SUM(Costo)`, but SQL Server doesn't allow to use aggregations within the `SET` clause.

Comment: That's why you use an updatable CTE, with window functions. Something like `with cte as (select *, summed = sum(Costo) over (partition by IDContratto from stageReg) update cte set ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti = summed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly updating an updatable CTE should prove to be faster, as you don't need to re-query `#Tab1`:

```sql
WITH costi AS (
    SELECT
      stage.ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti,
      stage.TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti,
      SUM(stageReg.Costo) OVER (PARTITION BY stage.IDContratto) AS Costo
    FROM #Tab1 AS stage
    INNER JOIN #Tab2 AS stageCom ON stage.CodiceContratto = stageCom.CodiceContrattoCommessa
    INNER JOIN #Tab3 AS stageReg
       ON stageCom.CodiceCommessa = stageReg.CodiceCommessaCalcolato
      AND stageReg.DataRegistrazione BETWEEN stage.StartDate AND stage.EndDate
    WHERE stageCom.SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa = 1
)
UPDATE costi
SET
  ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo,
  TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti += costi.Costo;
```

I would also recommend the following indexes:

```
stage (IDContratto) INCLUDE (CodiceContratto, StartDate, EndDate, ActualCostoCommesseNonFatturanti, TotaleCostoCommesseNonFatturanti)

stageCom (SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa, CodiceContrattoCommessa) INCLUDE (CodiceCommessa)

stageReg (CodiceCommessaCalcolato, DataRegistrazione) INCLUDE (Costo)
```

You could alternately make a filtered index on `stageCom`

```
stageCom (CodiceContrattoCommessa) INCLUDE (CodiceCommessa, SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa) WHERE (SeMotivoNonFatturabilePerditaCommessa = 1)
```

Comment: I didn't figure out I can do something like that with the CTEs. That seems smart, but unfortunately is ineffective: I executed your query (on the real tables, not the temps), it runs in 18 min. Then I created your suggested indexes and executed the query again. The actual exec plan shows that the second and the third are in use (not the first one, as in the case of `TabRegistrazioneOreRisorse` the index `IX_CostiCommessa` is in use). Nonetheless the query runs in 18 min. I'll yield you the actual exec plans as soon as I can.

Comment: No, I was wrong: I committed an error in creating the third index. Now that I found it the query runs in just 1 sec. The first two indexes doesn't affect performances: if I don't use them the query doesn't slow down, if I use _only_ them without the third one the query doesn't speed up. But the combination of the CTE plus the third index works perfectly. Thank you very much, what I learned here is invaluable.